# Python 2.7, pygame, combing pause and unpause button.

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a simple music player.

I have searched the other questions in Stackoverflow, however, the solutions do not work with my pygame build.

My code is below. I am using Tkinter for the gui build.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import pygame

myGui = Tk()


def mClose():
    mExit = tkMessageBox.askokcancel(title="Quit", message="are you sure?")
    if mExit ==True:
        myGui.destroy()
        return

def mPlay():    
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/david/Downloads/test.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()


def unPause():
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()        


def mPause():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()



myGui.title("My Audio")
myGui.geometry("200x200+600+300")
mLabel = Label(myGui, text="My Audio").pack()


''' Button for Closing App'''
mButton = Button(myGui, text="Close", command = mClose).pack()

'''Play Button'''
mButton = Button(myGui, text="Play", command = mPlay).pack()

'''Pause Button'''
mButton = Button(myGui, text="Pause", command = mPause).pack()

'''UnPause Button'''
mButton = Button(myGui, text="UnPause", command = unPause).pack()
```

I have tired to combine pause and unpause by using pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(). However, if it is paused the boolean still returns true for being active.

I have used the following to no avail:

```
def play_pause():
    paused = not paused
    if paused: pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    else: pygame.mixer.music.pause()
```

I get the following:

```
File "/home/david/Documents/tkinter_testing.py", line 29, in play_pause
    paused = not paused
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'paused' referenced before assignment.
```

Any ideas or help. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `paused` a value but calling itself for the value. I believe what you're looking for is

```
paused = False
```

or

```
paused = not True
```

Comment: He's using not paused to toggle the variable which I assume is a Boolean. not True is False and not False is True

Comment: @Decency That code he has will be correct if `paused` is initially assigned a value. But for the first time that the code runs `paused` does not have a value, which is throwing the error that it is referenced before assignment.

Comment: True! I assumed it was set initially but didn't notice the error. In that case he has two problems. :D

Comment: Here is what I have changed the code to per my reading the above. If I am wrong can you write your example given my format. I think the logic is lost in translation.

Comment: def play_pause():
    paused = False
    if paused == True: pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    else: pygame.mixer.music.pause()

Comment: When i run the above, the music pauses. However, when the button is pressed a second time the music does not restart.

Comment: @david_p You have to initially set `paused` a value. A global variable would be the best, as everytime you are calling the function you are reassigning `paused` to false. Instead have a global variable `paused = False` then in the play_pause() function use `paused = not paused`. You just had to set `paused` a value before changing it around.

Comment: So i set a global var outside my def play_pause(). Which is paused = False. Then in the function: 
def play_pause(): 
   paused = not paused    
   if paused: pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
   else: pygame.mixer.music.pause()

Comment: So i set a global var outside my def play_pause(). Which is paused = False. Then in the function: 
def play_pause(): 
   paused = not paused    
   if paused: pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
   else: pygame.mixer.music.pause()

I get the following error:  local variable 'paused' referenced before assignment

Thanks for all the help. This is just the part that is killing me on the logic

Comment: I solved the pause button as follows:

paused = False

def play_pause():
    global paused
    if paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        paused = False
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        paused = True

Thanks for all the help with the logic!!! Really was an eye opener!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic isn't correct.

Assume we start with the mixer paused, so:

```
paused is True
```

we call play_pause() to toggle it, and paused is set to not paused, so now:

```
paused is False
```

So we execute the else statement, and pause() the mixer, but it was already paused. The solution is to move the toggle to after the setting (which is probably the most clear) or to reverse the logic called from your if-else block.